# ASP.NET MVC 5 per user custom built views with widgets

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to make an MVC 5 app that will allow users to customize views/pages, create new ones. On the custom pages they can set-up widgets and be able to save the views. Also they should be able to setup the default view that will be loaded by default.

Any ideas how can I achieve this? I believe the views should be saved in the database.

EDIT:

I found this template engine [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). This seams to be what I am looking for. Anybody has any experience using RazorEngine?

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try some CMS like dotnetnuke etc. other wise build your own framework for all the things so that it can save and fetch your details to and from database.